# How to align two tikzpicture images inside minipages without body text overlapping?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

[image]

Why does the below lead to body text overlapping my images/image caption? How can I fix this? Apologies that I haven't provided a MWE, but this is using the `achemso` document class from Journal of the American Chemical Society.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[b][5cm][s]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \vfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}  
    \draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (4,0) node[right] {$x$};  
    \draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,4) node[above] {$y$};  
    \draw (0,0.5) -- (4,2.5);  
    \draw [dashed] (0,1.5) -- (4,3.5);  
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \vfill
    \caption{Two-site exchange. Two-site exchange. Two-site exchange. Two-site exchange. Two-site exchange. Two-site exchange. Two-site exchange. Two-site exchange.}\label{fig:simple2}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
\end{minipage}\qquad
\begin{minipage}[b][5cm][s]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \vfill
    \begin{tikzpicture}  
    \draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (4,0) node[right] {$x$};  
    \draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,4) node[above] {$y$};  
    \draw (0,0.5) -- (4,2.5);  
    \draw [dashed] (0,1.5) -- (4,3.5);  
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \vfill
    \caption{Partial three-site exchange.}\label{fig:partial3}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Replace `\begin{minipage}[b][5cm][s]{.45\textwidth}` with `\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
\begin{minipage}[b][5cm][s]{.45\textwidth}
```

with

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
```

and remove all `\vfill` commands to get the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass{achemso}
\usepackage{tikz}
\title{title}
\usepackage{lipsum} % Only for dummy text. Do not use in actual document.
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}  
    \draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (4,0) node[right] {$x$};  
    \draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,4) node[above] {$y$};  
    \draw (0,0.5) -- (4,2.5);  
    \draw [dashed] (0,1.5) -- (4,3.5);  
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \caption{Two-site exchange. Two-site exchange. Two-site exchange. Two-site exchange. Two-site exchange. Two-site exchange. Two-site exchange. Two-site exchange.}\label{fig:simple2}
\end{minipage}\qquad
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}  
    \draw[->] (-0.5,0) -- (4,0) node[right] {$x$};  
    \draw[->] (0,-0.5) -- (0,4) node[above] {$y$};  
    \draw (0,0.5) -- (4,2.5);  
    \draw [dashed] (0,1.5) -- (4,3.5);  
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \caption{Partial three-site exchange.}\label{fig:partial3}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}    
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!